# stop the extensions in VSCode from altering the right click menu

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using VScode for writing my Python codes. I'm using the 2 extensions `Pylance` and `Python`  for docstrings. However, I find it annoying that these extensions alter the mouse right-click menu, and the mouse right-click action. Is there any way to stop these extensions from modifying this?

Is there any way to remove all these unnecessary options from the right-click menu[image]?

Comment: modify the `package.json` of these extensions

Comment: Is there any simpler way to do this?